# Is it possible to extract confidence values for regression predictions in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, regression, confidence-interval

Can I extract the confidence values or variance in prediction error from a tensorflow regressor? e.g. if the model gives a prediction x, then can I know the confidence band, like is x in +-25% range of the actual value?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it's not as easy as when using sofmax in the output layer. As said in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network) you can use the MSE of the NN on the validation as an estimate for variance, then use your desired value of confidence. Be aware that this approach assumes a lot of things (ie. distribution of errors is allways the same which may not be true) so if you really need those confidence intervals, a regression NN is not the best fit for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @J63, need a little more help here though. When you say MSE of validation can be used for estimating the variance, that would be for the entire validation set right? I am looking to get confidence values for each element's prediction (regression based value) instead of an overall value for a whole test set. Any ideas around this?

Comment: Yes that would be for the whole validation set. As far as I know, it's impossible to do what you ask for a regression NN.